# SQL Query: Exclude sequential clusters from search if the cluster contains a specified value (snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running a query in snowflake. I am trying to identify clusters of equal sequential sales, and exclude the clusters from my search if they include a system account ('SystemA', 'SystemB' or 'SystemC'). My table is already sorted by date. I've pasted an image below and the highlighted rows are clusters that I'd like removed from the final output.

EDIT: My definition of a cluster wasn't too clear. I'm identifying clusters as duplicate Sales numbers that already sit above/below each other based on time. So in the example posted, the red section is highlighted because they all have sales values of 35. If the entry by Jeremy on 5/10/2021 was 35, it wouldn't included in the red cluster since it's separated by Jacob's entry of 20 on 5/10/2021. Since one of these rows in the red cluster includes a System account, I'd like to exclude the entire highlighted section from the query.

{[image: clustered rows highlighted]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqMP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html):

> Returns a window event number for each row within a window partition when the value of the argument expr1 in the current row is different from the value of expr1 in the previous row.

```
SELECT *,
    CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(ModifiedBy IN ('SystemA', 'SystemB', 'SystemC'))
    OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Timestamp) AS GRP
FROM tab
ORDER BY ID, Timestamp, GRP
```

With GRP column it is possible to filter out entire group, though the definition of cluster in the question is vague.

Comment: I'm identifying clusters as duplicate Sales numbers that already sit above/below each other based on time. So in the example posted, the red section is highlighted because they all have sales values of 35. Since one of these rows includes a System account, I'd like to exclude the entire highlighted section from the query.

Comment: @pickledpasta22 Then Sales should also be added to PARTTION BY clause. Anyway providing CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO to easily setup demo is much anticipated.

Comment: Noted, I'll add a demo setup for future questions. Thanks for the feedback.